# Freebsd 10.2 - multiple interfaces in the jail

Tags: networking, freebsd, chroot-jail

My old freebsd 8.0 has the following configuration (in the `/etc/rc.conf`) for the `xx` jail:

```
jail_xx_hostname="xx.example.com"
jail_xx_rootdir="/jails/xx"

#networking setup
jail_xx_ip="sis0|1.2.3.4,re0|10.10.10.4"
jail_xx_ip_multi0="tun0|10.5.0.1 10.5.0.2 mtu 1500 255.255.255.255"
jail_xx_devfs_ruleset="devfsrules_jail_xx"
```

E.g. have attached two different NICs (and plus one tun device to the jail).

How to achieve the same networking setup in Freebsd 10.2 using the `/etc/jail.conf`?

I tried:

```
xx {
    ip4.addr = "sis0|1.2.3.4,re0|10.10.10.4"
}
```

but got an error:

```
jail: xx: ip4.addr: not an IPv4 address: re0|10.10.10.4
```

Could someone help me how to attach two network interfaces (e.g. `sis0` and `re0`)to the jail in FreeBSD 10.2?

Whrere it is documented? I'm absolutely lost with the new `jail.conf` based jail configs... :(

*please, help*.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out the solution.

The documentation(jail.conf (5)) says the following example

> A comma-separated list of values may  be set in a single statement, or
>   an existing parameter list may be appended to using ``+='':

```
   ip4.addr = 10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.2, 10.1.1.3;

   ip4.addr = 10.1.1.1;
   ip4.addr += 10.1.1.2;
   ip4.addr += 10.1.1.3;
```

While the simple:

```
ip4.addr = "sis0|1.2.3.4,re0|10.10.10.4";
```

doesn't works, when I used the `+=` form, it finally does what i want. So, the solution is:

```
xx {
    ...
    interface = "sis0";
    ip4.addr += "sis0|1.2.3.4";
    ip4.addr += "re0|10.10.10.4";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Saved me lots of time, thanks for taking the time to add the answer!